# CPU L3 cache miss and hit ratio details

Tags: memory, cpu, redhat-enterprise-linux, cpu-cache

I am on a Linux server with [Xeon X7560](http://ark.intel.com/products/46499/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X7560-24M-Cache-2_26-GHz-6_40-GTs-Intel-QPI?q=X7560) CPU.

How can I see the CPU L3 cache miss and hit ratio details?

Comment: Which CPU model? Performance counters are not a standard CPU feature, and you do need hardware support for this.

Comment: CPU Model : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X7560  @ 2.27GHz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's an Intel CPU, you could try the [Intel adaptor that plugs into the KDE utility ksysguard](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor/)